# How design App Bar in Android Compose with back navigation and Image

Tags: android, kotlin, android-appbarlayout, android-jetpack-compose-ui

I am currently trying to create  Appbar with back navigation and image in Android Compose . How can I achieve this
Here I added the Image [Click here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9fX2.png)

In Android Compose how can we customize the App Bar with bacn navigation icon and Image.